# Is there a way to install h2o driverless ai on windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, time-series, h2o, driverless-ai

I am trying to install h2o driverless ai and so far I am unable to find any way. I am using jupyter notebook and I am unable to import h2oai_client.

My python version :

```
pip 20.0.2 from C:\Users\user\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

When i try to import h2oai_client, it says not found

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-afa0aad75588> in <module>
----> 1 from h2oai_client import Client

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h2oai_client'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install it on Windows 10 Pro / Enterprise / Education. You can follow [this doc](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/install/windows.html).

`h2oai_client` is the Python client. You would need to host Driverless AI on a server with the instructions above, then you can install the [client](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/python_install_client.html). Then you can connect to it using the Python client.